# How change string2 to string3 only on lines containing string1?

Tags: vi

My aim is to search `string1` in all lines, and find and replace `string2` by `string3` on those lines.

File content:

```
Here is my first line
Second line with string1 & string2
Not last line but it contains string1
```

Expected Output

```
Here is my first line
The second line with string1 & string3
Not last line but it contains string1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The following command does what you want:

```
:g/string1/s/string2/string3/g
```

where the last `g` is the flag for global substitution (substitute all occurrences on the line).

Comment: @NishantPrabhakar then accepting the answer would be appropriate, don't you think?